similarity_search with chromadb and default setting returns 4 identical document objects
i'm new to vectorstore and in general doing my first steps with RAG
relevant pip freeze info:
chroma-hnswlib==0.7.3
chromadb==0.4.24
langchain==0.1.13
langchain-community==0.0.29
langchain-core==0.1.34
langchain-text-splitters==0.0.1

here is the code:
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.document_loaders import PyPDFLoader
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings



loader = PyPDFLoader("paper1.pdf")
pages = loader.load()
pages = pages[9:360]
text = ""
for page in pages:
    text += page.page_content
text = text.replace('\t', ' ')
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(separators=["\n\n", "\n", "\t"], chunk_size=chunk_size,
                                               chunk_overlap=chunk_overlap)
docs = text_splitter.create_documents([text])

DB = Chroma.from_documents(docs,SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6- 
v2"),persist_directory="./chroma_db")
most_similar = self.DB.similarity_search(
        'some sentence about apples')

so far things work well, but when i inspect most_similar this is what i see.
[Document(page_content='bla bla bla apples bla bla bla'), Document(page_content='bla bla bla 
               apples bla bla bla'), Document(page_content='bla bla bla apples bla bla bla'),  
               Document(page_content='bla bla bla apples bla bla bla')]

the point being, the same chunk is being retrieved again and again.

Can you show your docs sample before you enter it into the chromadb. I'm guessing the issue is with the way you are processing data. Since chromadb would return N most similar documents. It should not be able to pick same index in a single query. So probably your text processing is not working correctly.

Can't reproduce your problem. Running your code gives expected response.

not sure how to show the docs sample, its a list with length 202, the elements inside the list are of type <class 'langchain_core.documents.base.Document'>, this object has a single attribute page_content which contains the strings, i see them and they are not problematic. it also has has other attributes such as lc_secrets (empty dict), lc_secrets (empty dict), metadata (empty dict), Config  (<class 'langchain_core.load.serializable.Serializable.Config'> extra 'ignore')

Garbage In, Garbage Out. Please use better examples.

@Yilmaz it seems like a very similar situation but I'm not sure how to get anything from it. does it mean that my documents are already loaded from the persist directory and somehow it effects the output?

after helpful discussions with commentators i realized there is no automatic saving and loading, even though the persisted_dir is specified.
i implemented a class to do all the handling, attaching it here for anyone interested
import chromadb
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma


class DocumentHandler:
def __init__(self, document_name, docs, embedding_model_name, persist_directory):

    self.persistent_client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=persist_directory)
    self.collection_name = document_name
    self.docs = docs
    self.langchain_chroma = None
    self.embedding_function = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name = embedding_model_name)
    self.initialize_chroma_langchain_object()

def initialize_chroma_langchain_object(self):
    # Check if 'my_collection' exists and create if it does not
    try:
        self.collection = self.persistent_client.get_collection(self.collection_name)
        print(f"Collection '{self.collection_name}' loaded successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"coudln't load collection '{self.collection_name}'.\n{e}\nCreating and adding documents...")
        self.collection = self.persistent_client.create_collection(name=self.collection_name)
        ids, documents = zip(*[(str(id), doc.page_content) for id, doc in enumerate(self.docs)])
        self.collection.add(ids=list(ids), documents=list(documents))

    # Instantiate the LangChain Chroma object
    self.langchain_chroma = Chroma(
        client=self.persistent_client,
        collection_name=self.collection_name,
        embedding_function=self.embedding_function,  # Ensure embedding_function is defined
    )

    # Display the number of documents in the collection
    print(f"There are {self.langchain_chroma._collection.count()} documents in the collection.")

